# How inclusion-exclusion works demonstrated on an set example

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, inclusion-exclusion

In the inclusion-exclusion set example:

> $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$

we subtract $|A\cap B\cap C|$ three times because it is included in $|A\cap B|$,$|A\cap C|$ and $|B\cap C|$,
but we are adding it back only once as $+|A\cap B\cap C|$. Why? Common sense says: we should add it back twice if we subtracted it three times.

Please explain using simple words :)

Comment: Actually common sense says: we should add it back $4$ times *if* we subtracted it $3$ times (because the cardinality is also counted on LHS). But common sense also says that (on RHS) we did not only subtracted it $3$ times but also added it $3$ times. So adding back once is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we added $|A\cap B\cap C|$ three times because $A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Then we subtracted it again three times because $A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of $A\cup B$, $A\cup C$ and $B\cup C$.

Then we add it once so that it present exactly one time, as it should.

Comment: $A\cup B\cup C$ should probably be $A\cap B\cap C$...

Comment: @5xum Thank you. Repaired.

Answer (score 3):

Let us make an explicit case by case check  for the possible of a choice of $x\in A\cup B\cup C$.

- If $x$ is in exactly one of the three sets, w.l.o.g. in $A$, then it is counted as follows: $1= (1+0+0)-(0+0+0)+0$.
- If $x$ is in exactly two of the three sets, w.l.o.g. in $A\cap B$, then it is counted as follows: $1= (1+1+0)-(1+0+0)+0$.
- If $x$ is in exactly three of the three sets, so in $A\cap B\cap C$, then it is counted as follows: $1= (1+1+1)-(1+1+1)+1$.

For each $x\in A\cup B\cup C$ we have the same contribution on both sides.

Euler diagrams may make things clear in a visual way.